# Integrating Sensirion SCD-30 with ESP32-S2 into Espressif IDF

Tags: esp32, sensors

As the title may suggest, I want to integrate the sensirion SCD-30 with the ESP32 into the Espressif IDF Development Area. However the Github project I found (link: https://github.com/pantaluna/esp32_scd30_sensor_settings_using_lib) doesn't specify on how to do that it seems like this project does also not show which IDE it is using. There are already tons of examples on how to use the MCU with the sensor on the Arduino IDE but unfortunately not on the Espressif IDF..

Greetings,

Gorkem

I already cloned the project, did run it on Espressif IDF but I cannot find the logging data.